# Lucene index searching from text file

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to search a lucene index from a text file that contains keywords instead of including the keywords in the code. In the code below, the keyword "book" is searched in the Lucene index. Instead of this method, I want to read a txt file that will contain the keyword I want to search Do you have any idea on how I can implement this concept in the code below?

```
public class Searcher
{

    public void searchIndex(String instring) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        System.out.println("Searching for ' " + instring +  " '");          
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(FSDirectory.open(new File("C:\\indexing\\full")));
        Analyzer analyzer1 = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
        QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34,"content", analyzer1);
        QueryParser queryParserfilename = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34,"fullpath",analyzer1);
        Query query = queryParser.parse(instring);
        Query queryfilename = queryParserfilename.parse(instring);        
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 100);
        ScoreDoc[] document = hits.scoreDocs;

        System.out.println("Total no of hits for content: " + hits.totalHits);
        for(int i = 0;i <document.length;i++)
        {                 
            Document doc = searcher.doc(document[i].doc);      
            String filePath = doc.get("fullpath");                                      
            System.out.println(filePath);
        }

        TopDocs hitfilename = searcher.search(queryfilename,100);
        ScoreDoc[] documentfilename = hitfilename.scoreDocs;
        System.out.println("Occurrence:" + hitfilename.totalHits);       
        for(int i = 0;i < documentfilename.length ; i++)
        {
            Document doc = searcher.doc(documentfilename[i].doc);
            String filename= doc.get("filename");
            System.out.println(filename);                   
        } 
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {  
            new Searcher().searchIndex("book");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Searcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Searcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time: " + (endTime - startTime));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just read the text file in with a `BufferedReader`?

Comment: Don't use a query parser, build the boolean query yourself.